# Allow inlining in specific headers in debug mode Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inlining

Is it possible to have a build setting in which specific headers are allowed
to be inlined in a debug build? I am using the signal/delegate pattern alot which I test in a separate project. I would like my main project not to show the signal/delegate parts of the callbacks in the call stack when I am hitting a breakpoint. Is it possible to allow inlining functions on a header only library, without optimizing the main project, or is there some other way to filter the calls to the header only library from the call stack interface.

Comment: A breakpoint without call-stack information is really worthless. How would the debugger know which inline function you're really in? How could you actually set a breakpoint in the inlined function itself if it isn't really "called"? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by dropping call-stack information? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I don't want to step into the library functions, the callback structures can get quite complex and I want them to be invisible in the call stack. I want to assume the callbacks work because I unit test the library separately.

Comment: So you mean you want to *step over* certain function calls? Then why don't you do that? All debuggers should have both *step into* and *step over* functionality. I know for a fact that the Visual Studio debugger have it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think OP wants to step into the callback from where it is passed to the library, skipping the library stuff. E.g. breakpoint on `Library::SomeHOF([](){ /*want to step to here*/ })`,

Comment: @Caleth Then why not set a (*temporary*) breakpoint in the callback before calling the library function? It's easy and very quick.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude indeed. Or something like VS's run to cursor (Ctrl F10)

Comment: You may also consider this undocumented feature to tell the debugger not to stop in the library you are using: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andypennell/2004/02/06/how-to-not-step-into-functions-using-the-visual-c-debugger/. Not sure if it still works, but the file mentioned for VS2012 still exists in VS 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try `#pragma optimize` :

```
#pragma optimize( "g", {on | off} )
```

This work on a function-by-function basis.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

You will probably need to activate inlining in debug mode, opt-out by default and opt-in for specific functions.